# Uploading JAR's to Web server

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I am looking to upload binaries to my webserver when I build so that the I can easily update the app from my webserver however whenever searching around it it only find relevance to servants and tomcat deployment.

Is there a functionality on eclipse that can do this or if not a plugging for eclipse.

Sorry if this should have been posted on super user I was not entirely sure if it should be posted here or there.

Comment: Seriously? do you want to upload jar files to web servers ? did you mean war file ?

Comment: No I want to put them on a webserver so that my programs can download updates from the server nothing to do with war/servlets at all

Comment: Why you want to them in server put them out side the tomcat server ! 
put them at  D:\  or something like that

Comment: I want them deployed to a server so users can update and my server is not local

Comment: update on what ?

Comment: if they are Jars file they can't be accessible from tomact server you have to make ftp connection in order to let your users update using jars files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Remote System Explorer (part of Eclipse's Target Management (TM) project)](https://www.eclipse.org/tm/tutorial/index.php). It allows you to interact with remote systems, such as FTP or other servers, right from within Eclipse.

Note that RSE is included by default in some of the Eclipse IDE packages: Java EE, C/C++, Javascript/Web, and Java/Report. See [this page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=neon). If you don't have one of those packages, you can install the TM features into your Eclipse: see the RSE update repository listed on [this page](https://www.eclipse.org/tm/downloads.php).